# Access 2016 - SQL Sum Query Doesn't Provide Sum, No errors

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

### Goal / Problem

What I am trying to do is fairly simple. I have two fields, `InvoiceNbr` and `TransAmt`. In the table, there may be multiple transactions for each invoice. So I'm simply trying to sum all transactions for each invoice number so I'll have one transaction sum for each invoice number (which I can later subtract from a balance to get the remaining balance). Sounds simple, and typically is... but I'm having an issue (or bug? that DOES NOT result in an error)!

### My Data

Here is a query that will give a snippet of my data:

```
SELECT [_MasterLog_Transactions].InvoiceNbr, [_MasterLog_Transactions].TransAmt
FROM _MasterLog_Transactions
GROUP BY [_MasterLog_Transactions].InvoiceNbr, [_MasterLog_Transactions].TransAmt
HAVING ((([_MasterLog_Transactions].InvoiceNbr)="16081702014741") 
AND (([_MasterLog_Transactions].TransAmt)>0));
```

This results in:

```
InvoiceNbr      TransAmt
16081702014741  $1,096.73
16081702014741  $3,668.25
```

If I add a 'totals' row using the Access GUI, and choose "SUM", it correctly calculates "$4,764.98". And for other random reference, in the `_MasterLog_Transactions` table, `TransAmt` is a 'number' field, field size 'double', and format 'currency' -- so it should be capable of being used with the SUM function.

### My Query

So working from the above data, I created the query:

```
SELECT [_MasterLog_Transactions].InvoiceNbr, 
       Sum([_MasterLog_Transactions].TransAmt) AS MyTest
FROM _MasterLog_Transactions
GROUP BY [_MasterLog_Transactions].InvoiceNbr
HAVING ((([_MasterLog_Transactions].InvoiceNbr)="16081702014741"));
```

### My Query Results

```
InvoiceNbr      MyTest
16081702014741  $1,096.73
```

I would have expected:

```
InvoiceNbr      MyTest
16081702014741  $4,764.98
```

No errors occur. It runs and Access seems to think it is outputting the proper result.

Am I overlooking something really simple here, or is this an Access bug I've never run into? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a `HAVING` clause instead of a `WHERE` clause?  Are you certain that the `InvoiceNbr` is *exactly* `16081702014741` in both cases? (E.g. there isn't a space or unprintable character hanging about in the value that would make it not equal to `16081702014741`).  Try running a `SELECT` statement with that `WHERE` clause to see what you have in the data.

Comment: @Siyual - Attempted a where clause, but received same results. Thanks for the suggestion though! As for the 'space' issue - this is happening with thousands of accounts. But just to double check, the first query in my original question essentially checks for that (the first query found two transactions with that exact string -- I've also attempted "trim()" in my troubleshooting prior to asking here, so we're on the same page ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please check for space in the InvoiceNbr.
- You can verify that this is an InvoiceNbr issue by adding COUNT(*) to your query.

Comment: BAH! I'm so stupid. You'll notice in **My Data** that I search for `AND (([_MasterLog_Transactions].TransAmt)>0))`. It should have been `<>0`. This kept me from seeing two negative records, which resulted in my assumption of the "correct value" being off! Wouldn't have caught it without the COUNT(*) troubleshooting though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the equivalent query would look more like this:

```
SELECT t.InvoiceNbr, 
       Sum(t.TransAmt) AS MyTest
FROM _MasterLog_Transactions as t
WHERE t.InvoiceNbr = "16081702014741" AND
      t.TransAmt > 0
GROUP BY t.InvoiceNbr;
```

I'm guessing your real summarized data looks like:

```
InvoiceNbr      TransAmt
16081702014741   $1,096.73
16081702014741   $3,668.25
16081702014741  -$3,668.25
```

That is the condition `[_MasterLog_Transactions].TransAmt > 0` is filtering out key values.

Comment: you are 100% right, thanks for the response. I caught my mistake as soon as I used Dudu's troubleshooting of "count(*)" and noticed extra records. Annoyingly simple mistake on my end - but hopefully someone can benefit from the troubleshooting suggestion.